# I am trying to pivot a file using awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting, solaris

I am trying to pivot a file using awk.
Input File:

FA-1D_005   10000090fa180e49
FA-2D_006   10000090fa180e49
FA-2D_011   10000090fa180e49
FA-3D_004   10000090fa180e49
FA-4D_005   10000090fa180e49
FA-2D_004   20010090fa180e49
FA-2D_008   20010090fa180e49
FA-3D_004   20010090fa180e49
FA-1D_006   20020090fa180e49
FA-4D_004   20020090fa180e49
FA-1D_006   20030090fa180e49
FA-4D_004   20030090fa180e49
FA-2D_006   20040090fa180e49
FA-2D_009   20040090fa180e49
FA-3D_005   20040090fa180e49
FA-1D_006   10000090fa180e48
FA-1D_011   10000090fa180e48
FA-2D_006   10000090fa180e48
FA-3D_005   10000090fa180e48
FA-4D_006   10000090fa180e48
FA-1D_004   20010090fa180e48
FA-2D_006   20010090fa180e48
FA-2D_011   20010090fa180e48
FA-3D_004   20010090fa180e48
FA-3D_006   20010090fa180e48
FA-4D_005   20010090fa180e48
FA-1D_006   20020090fa180e48
FA-2D_004   20020090fa180e48
FA-2D_010   20020090fa180e48
FA-3D_004   20020090fa180e48
FA-4D_004   20020090fa180e48
FA-3D_005   20030090fa180e48
FA-3D_007   20030090fa180e48
FA-1D_005   20040090fa180e48

### Desired output

FA-1D_005   10000090fa180e49
FA-2D_006
FA-2D_011
FA-3D_004

### FA-4D_005

FA-2D_004   20010090fa180e49
FA-2D_008

### FA-3D_004

FA-1D_006   20020090fa180e49

### FA-4D_004

FA-1D_006   20030090fa180e49

### FA-4D_004

FA-2D_006   20040090fa180e49
FA-2D_009

### FA-3D_005

FA-1D_006   10000090fa180e48
FA-1D_011
FA-2D_006
FA-3D_005

### FA-4D_006

FA-1D_004   20010090fa180e48
FA-2D_006
FA-2D_011
FA-3D_004
FA-3D_006

### FA-4D_005

FA-1D_006   20020090fa180e48
FA-2D_004
FA-2D_010
FA-3D_004

### FA-4D_004

FA-3D_005   20030090fa180e48

### FA-3D_007

### FA-1D_005   20040090fa180e48

Kindly let know which is the best approach to generate a pivot table?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: spend some time in formatting the question to get more answers....

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==1{hr=sprintf("%"length($0)"s"," ");gsub(" ","-",hr)} 
            {print (p==$2?$1:hr "\n" $0); p=$2} 
         END{print hr}' file

---------------------------
FA-1D_005  10000090fa180e49
FA-2D_006
FA-2D_011
FA-3D_004
FA-4D_005
---------------------------
FA-2D_004  20010090fa180e49
FA-2D_008
FA-3D_004
---------------------------
FA-1D_006  20020090fa180e49
FA-4D_004
---------------------------
FA-1D_006  20030090fa180e49
FA-4D_004
---------------------------
FA-2D_006  20040090fa180e49
FA-2D_009
FA-3D_005
---------------------------
FA-1D_006  10000090fa180e48
FA-1D_011
FA-2D_006
FA-3D_005
FA-4D_006
---------------------------
FA-1D_004  20010090fa180e48
FA-2D_006
FA-2D_011
FA-3D_004
FA-3D_006
FA-4D_005
---------------------------
FA-1D_006  20020090fa180e48
FA-2D_004
FA-2D_010
FA-3D_004
FA-4D_004
---------------------------
FA-3D_005  20030090fa180e48
FA-3D_007
---------------------------
FA-1D_005  20040090fa180e48
---------------------------
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error. My OS is solaris [SunOS hostname 5.10 Generic_150401-38 i86pc i386 i86pc]

awk 'NR==1{hr=sprintf("%"length($0)"s"," ");gsub(" ","-",hr)}{print (p==$2?$1:hr "\n" $0); p=$2}END{print hr}' kay.txt
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1

Comment: On Solaris you need to locate the working `awk`, the default one is broken as far as I know.  This code might be using `GNU awk` specific extensions.  Try to find `gawk`.

Comment: There's nothing gawk-specific in there, it'd work with any POSIX awk. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk as it's the closest to POSIX conformant on Solaris and will work with that script. Never use /bin/awk on Solaris as that is old, broken awk and must never be used. Solaris should have removed it years ago.

Comment: @EdMorton *Solaris should have removed it years ago.* And doing **that** would break existing software dependent upon the pre-standardized behavior of `/bin/awk`.

Comment: Solaris, no more :(

Comment: @AndrewHenle I understand Suns excuse for not removing it but tools get deprecated all the time and we get by and the thing is **broken**. Deprecating it would have been better than living with this ridiculous situation where there's a buggy awk that behaves differently from all other awks that people are constantly tripping over. They could have left it lying around as `oawk` for anyone who wanted the old, broken functionality rather than leaving it as the default awk. They've had 33 years so far to fix this problem (since `nawk` was invented in 1985)!

Comment: @EdMorton So your solution would be to change something out from under existing code, with `/bin/awk` behaving differently depending on which exact version of Solaris you're running on?  Do you specifically aim for nine 5s for your system availability?  "[W]e get by" is an awfully low standard to aim for.

Comment: @AndrewHenle it's a tradeoff between replacing a broken tool so everyone for the next 30 years and beyond doesn't have to keep tripping over the breakage, or leaving the broken tool in place in case someone has written code that relies on that breakage. Obviously you think Sun made the right choice and I strongly disagree having seen the resultant wreckage in horrible, hacky awk scripts trying to work around the breakage over the years as well as the thousands of people wasting time wondering why they get syntax errors and inexplicable output and asking questions on forums like this one.

Comment: @AndrewHenle you might be interested in this article I wrote years ago about why old, broken awk should be avoided: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.awk/AgPsgOWp_to/AgKDjsNIdNkJ. You could debate whether many of the items listed are breakage or, as some clearly are, just extremely annoying conformance to an old "standard" but in particular note the bugs demonstrated in item 6 and the 2nd part of item 16. Leaving that mess as the default awk instead of replacing it 30+ years ago, even if it meant a few scripts had to change to call `oawk` instead of `awk`, was just a terrible idea.